# XSLT 1.0 Test deviation

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

How to check two values to see if they are different? -> Concerns the nodes `Item.DeliveryDate` and `Item.OrigDeliveryDate`.

If yes, a new node `LineChangeDeliveryDate` should be created with the value `yes`, otherwise with the value `no`.

XML at the moment:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OrderResponse>
  <Interchange>    
    <Interchange_Control_Number>5637248870</Interchange_Control_Number>
  </Interchange>
  <HeaderInformation>
    <ConfirmDocNum>SO0009783-1</ConfirmDocNum>   
    <TransportDetails>
      <DeliveryMode>ROU</DeliveryMode>
    </TransportDetails>   
  </HeaderInformation>
  <LineInformation>
    <Item>      
      <DeliveryDate>2020-01-27</DeliveryDate>
      <OrigDeliveryDate>2019-12-07</OrigDeliveryDate>
    </Item>
  </LineInformation>
</OrderResponse>
```

XML new/correct:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OrderResponse>
  <Interchange>    
    <Interchange_Control_Number>5637248870</Interchange_Control_Number>
  </Interchange>
  <HeaderInformation>
    <ConfirmDocNum>SO0009783-1</ConfirmDocNum>   
    <TransportDetails>
      <DeliveryMode>ROU</DeliveryMode>
    </TransportDetails>   
  </HeaderInformation>
  <LineInformation>
    <Item>      
      <DeliveryDate>2020-01-27</DeliveryDate>
      <OrigDeliveryDate>2019-12-07</OrigDeliveryDate>
      <LineChangeDeliveryDate>yes</LineChangeDeliveryDate>
    </Item>
  </LineInformation>
</OrderResponse>
```

Current XSLT:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:key name="header_text" match="HeaderText" use="Text"/>
  <xsl:key name="line_text" match="LineText" use="concat(../LineNum, '|', Text)"/>
  <xsl:key name="allowance_charge_header" match="AllowanceOrCharge_Header" use="concat(Code, '|', Amount)"/>
  <xsl:key name="allowance_charge_line" match="AllowanceOrCharge_Line" use="concat(../LineNum, '|', Code, '|', Amount)"/>
  <xsl:key use="concat(../LineNum, '|', Text)" match="LineText" name="line_text"/>

  <!-- Identity-Template für die nicht explizit benannten Elemente -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="HeaderText[generate-id() != generate-id(key('header_text', Text)[1])]" />
  <xsl:template match="LineText[generate-id() != generate-id(key('line_text', concat(../LineNum, '|', Text))[1])]" />
  <xsl:template match="AllowanceOrCharge_Header[generate-id() != generate-id(key('allowance_charge_header', concat(Code, '|', Amount))[1])]" />
  <xsl:template match="AllowanceOrCharge_Line[generate-id() != generate-id(key('allowance_charge_line', concat(../LineNum, '|', Code, '|', Amount))[1])]" />
  <xsl:template match="LineText[generate-id() != generate-id(key('line_text', concat(../LineNum, '|', Text))[1])]"/>

  <xsl:template match="Item">
    <xsl:copy>
      <LineChangeDeliveryDate>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="OrigDeliveryDate = DeliveryDate"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="'yes'"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="'no'"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </LineChangeDeliveryDate>
      <!--copy all other nodes-->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- delete empty nodes -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[not(@*|*|comment()|processing-instruction()) and normalize-space()='']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the template rule with `match="Item"`, do

```
<LineChangeDeliveryDate>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="OrigDeliveryDate = DeliveryDate">
       <xsl:value-of select="'yes'/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
       <xsl:value-of select="'no'/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</LineChangeDeliveryDate>
```

This is one of many cases where the XSLT 2.0 code is much more concise:

```
<LineChangeDeliveryDate>
       <xsl:value-of select="if (OrigDeliveryDate = DeliveryDate) then 'yes' else 'no'"/>
</LineChangeDeliveryDate>
```

and in 3.0 it reduces further to

```
<LineChangeDeliveryDate>{
  if (OrigDeliveryDate = DeliveryDate) then 'yes' else 'no'
}</LineChangeDeliveryDate>
```

Comment: You've put the code in a template that matches `LineInformation`, not `Item`, so the context node is wrong.

Comment: corrected  but error-message:   Error reported by XML parser: The element type "xsl:choose" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</xsl:choose>".

Comment: <xsl:when test="OrigDeliveryDate = DeliveryDate"/> has an extra slash on the end

Comment: I like to make sure that people have to read and understand the code rather than just copying it blindly ;-). Hopefully that means they won't have to ask so many questions in future.

Comment: Good answer, +1 from my side! Michael, it is time for your XSLT 3.0 book release.